Trouble locating button element in selenium using python
I'm trying to locate a button element:
<button rpl="" class="login w-100
button-large px-[var(--rem14)]
button-brand



items-center justify-center
button inline-flex " type="button">

I tried locating it by the class name but when I copied it using inspect element in the browser it was formatted with spaces and 3 line breaks like so:
login w-100
button-large px-[var(--rem14)]
button-brand



items-center justify-center
button inline-flex 

I tried the following without the line breaks but it failed:
button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'login w-100 button-large px-[var(-rem14)] button-brand items-center justify-center button inline-flex')))

How do I correctly specify the class name?

By.CLASS_NAME, 'login w-100 button-large px-[var(-rem14)] button-brand items-center justify-center button inline-flex'

Above is incorrect. You cannot use CLASS_NAME locator strategy when there are multiple classes.
Try XPATH locator strategy instead:
By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'login w-100')]"

Above XPath locator will work if //button[contains(@class,'login w-100')] this XPath expression locates 1 element(the targeted element) when you try to inspect element in your browser. Try it first.

I tried searching //button[contains(@class,'login w-100')] in inspect element but it didn't find anything. I also tried just copying the xpath and css selector from the button element and searched for those but it didn't find anything. Strange as this worked for the other elements on the page, its just that button element that's giving me trouble.

Can you share the URL of the site if it's public? If not, edit your question and share the full HTML of the page.
